# What should this be tagged?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, tagging

[This question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/if-people-are-building-ai-systems-will-the-programming-also-be-aggressiveness-o) seems to me to be on-topic, but I can't figure out what it should be tagged.

It's currently tagged [computer-programming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-programming), which is obviously incorrect - see the tag wiki (that I wrote :P). I thought about [philosophy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy), but that didn't really seem to fit either.

So, **what should this be tagged**?

Answer (score 1):

One decent option that already exists is [human-like](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-like). It currently only has two questions: one comparing human brains with neural networks, and one about AIs lying to humans. This question is about whether AIs' personalities can be distinguished into categories like those used for humans'. Since personalities are a human-like thing to have*, it would seem to fit in that tag as it's used so far. I suggested an edit that replaced the incorrect tag with this one, and it was approved by the post owner.

In my understanding, that specific question only applies to general AIs (as opposed to something like an image recognizer). Therefore, [agi](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agi) could also be relevant.

<sup>*Yes, animals can have personalities too. Animals can also [deceive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deception_in_animals).</sup>

Comment: How about tagging it as 'behavioural'? This generalizes the human/animal distinction and also means that the system need not be a general intelligence.